# How to an HTML 5 submit button which change color based on the form values without any scripting language?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a form validation with Just HTML5 with Submit button style changes depends on the all the input validation values. ie to display Color of submit button in green if all the input fields are valid /Form is valid .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the submit button based on the [form's `:valid` or `:invalid` pseudo-class](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-valid):

```css
form:valid input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #cfc;
  color: #060;
}

form:invalid input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #fcc;
  color: #600;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Serial number:
    <input pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3}" required placeholder="Something like ABC123">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" required>
    One of these
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" required>
    must be selected
  </label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only validation that can be done with just HTML is to use the HTML5 'required' attribute which doesn't let a form to be submitted before you do something (click a radio button, fill a text field...).

You can't validate a form to your own likes, and you certainly can't dynamically change elements' CSS properties without JavaScript.

Comment: _"The only validation that can be done with just HTML is to use the HTML5 'required' attribute"_ [Not quite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression).